# How to close mobile menu when click on hamburger icon using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have created a mobile menu that is opening fine when I click on the "hamburger" icon. (Not an image, created with divs and css). I am having some trouble figuring out how to close the mobile menu when a user clicks on the "hamburger" icon. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

```
const hamburgerBtn = document.getElementById("hamburger");
const navLink = document.querySelector(".nav__links");

navLink.style.left = "-100%";
hamburgerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if ((navLink.style.left = "-100%")) {
    navLink.style.left = "0%";
  }
});
```

Code above is how I am able to make the mobile menu appear.

Answer (score 2):

After your if add an else to make it back to the -100% position

```
const hamburgerBtn = document.getElementById("hamburger");
const navLink = document.querySelector(".nav__links");

navLink.style.left = "-100%";
hamburgerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

      if ((navLink.style.left == "-100%")) {
        navLink.style.left = "0%";
      } else {
        navLink.style.left = "-100%";
       }

});
```

Comment: You answered faster than me, my friend. I gave up adding a copy of the same as an answer. +1

Comment: Thank you crg for your tip, yet it is still not working :/

Comment: Your first operator is a single `=` sign. It will not work

Comment: Good eyes @ProsyArceno Thx I have surely answer too faster and haven't seen that.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ternary operator to check the `left style`.

Basically,

`condition ? true case : false case`

```js
const hamburgerBtn = document.getElementById("hamburger");
const navLink = document.querySelector(".nav__links");

navLink.style.left = "-100%";
hamburgerBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  navLink.style.left =  navLink.style.left ==="-100%" ? "0" : "-100%";
});
```

```css
.nav__links {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button id="hamburger">NAV</button>
<div class="nav__links">
  HEY
</div>
```

.

Comment: Thank you Prosy, a ternary operator is the same as an if else statement correct? I tried to use the previous answer before yours thinking it would work, but when i used your answer (thank you) it did. Why is that? If you can explain would be great!

Comment: It simply is `condition ? true case : false case`, in your case, `navLink.style.left === "-100%" ? "0" : "-100%"`. `navLink.style.left === "-100%` is the condition, if it is true then you use `"0"`. If false you use `"-100%"`.